# Python list filter

Tags: python

am having a list

```
vals=[3.0, 3.03, 3.06, 3.09, 3.12, 3.15, 3.18, 3.21, 3.24, 3.27, 3.3, 3.33, 3.36, 3.39, 3.42, 3.45, 3.48, 3.51, 3.54, 3.57, 4.0, 4.03, 4.06, 4.09, 4.12, 4.15, 4.18, 4.21, 4.24, 4.27, 4.3, 4.33, 4.36, 4.39, 4.42, 4.45, 4.48, 4.51, 4.54, 4.57, 4.6, 5.0, 5.03, 5.06, 5.09, 5.12, 5.15, 5.18, 5.21, 5.24, 5.27, 5.3, 5.33, 5.36, 5.39, 5.42, 5.45, 5.48, 5.51, 5.54, 5.57, 5.6, 6.0, 6.03]
```

i need to filter the list and need to remove all the decimal point  values grater or equal to .6

how can i filter it ? any help would be appreciated . Thank you !

i had done it in a way but all the values are not removed some still existing

```
for i in vals:
        hour, minute = divmod(i, 1)
        print(minute)
        if minute >= .6:
            vals.remove(i)
```

Comment: Don't modify a list that you are iterating over.

Comment: Show an example of what you want the list to look like after processing. From the looks of your example list, everything would be removed since every element is > 0.6.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate - at least the linked duplicate won't help the OP here.

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following

```
vals = [number for number in vals if ((number%1) <0.6)]
```